# Where to find the blockchain on Bitcoin ABC?

Tags: bitcoin-cash, datadir, ecash

So if I'm running a full node on Bitcoin ABC, where can I find the file or files which contain the blockchain when it is being downloaded?
The folder in Program Files is too small, I think, to contain the blockchain.

Comment: For future readers: the Bitcoin-ABC client is (confusingly) not a Bitcoin client.

Answer (score 3):

As per the documentation https://github.com/Bitcoin-ABC/bitcoin-abc/blob/master/doc/files.md

```
blocks/blk000??.dat: block data (custom, 128 MiB per file); since 0.8.0
```

These files should be in `C:/Users/(username)/AppData/Roaming/Bitcoin` which is the standard app data directory.